# Display an image in a table cell in powerpoint programmatically

Tags: c#, powerpoint, embedded-resource

I need the ability to add an image into a dynamic table created in C# within powerpoint.  Is there anyway to do this?  The only thing I can think of right now is to display the image and overlay it on the table, but this is NOT the preferred method ...

```
PowerPoint.Table objTable = objSlide.Shapes.AddTable(1, 2, StartX, StartY, Width, Height).Table;
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Look at my image -->";
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 14;

Bitmap fileImage = new Bitmap(MyWinApp.Properties.Resources.image);

// ???????????????
objTable.Cell(1, 2). .... = fileImage;
// ???????????????
```

Cant find an answer on Google and Im not seeing any properties of the cell that will allow an image.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure a table does not support embedded shapes like images. The only workaround a can think of is adding the picture as bullet image for a paragraph like this:

```
tableShape.Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange. _
    ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Picture ("C:\path\to\image.jpg")
```

You just need to keep in mind that the size of the bullet (= image size) scales with the paragraph's font size and the bullet/image will be hidden when the paragraph has no text (but a space character will do).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Shape.Fill.UserPicture(fileImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching a solution for the same problem and found one like this, maybe not the best one: writing the image into your local disk and insert the image file into the PowerPoint.

As Rory and Nazim had posted, you can write the image into a temp file, say, "xx.tmp".  Then

```
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Shape.Fill.UserPicture("xx.tmp");
```

In this way, you insert the image as the *background image* into the table cell.

Also, you can insert the image into the slide (not the table), and set its location and size manually:

```
slide.Shapes.AddPicture("xx.tmp", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, 50, 60, 30,30);
```

In this way, you insert the image into the slide like a normal "copy/paste" operation.